# Extracting key,values from a dictionary as a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, unix-timestamp

I have a dictionary that I have extracted from a json url that has 6 keys. My interest is only in the values for the key `'value'`. The data is structured like this:

```
    [in] print(data)
    [out] ...'values': [{'x': 1230940800, 'y': 0}, 
{'x': 1231113600, 'y': 0}, 
{'x': 1231286400, 'y': 0}, 
{'x': 1231459200, 'y': 0}, 
{'x': 1231632000, 'y': 0}, 
{'x': 1231804800, 'y': 0}, 
{'x': 1231977600, 'y': 0}, 
{'x': 1232150400, 'y': 0}, 
{'x': 1232323200, 'y': 0}, 
{'x': 1232496000, 'y': 0}, 
{'x': 1232668800, 'y': 0}, 
{'x': 1232841600, 'y': 0}, 
{'x': 1233014400, 'y': 0}, 
{'x': 1233187200, 'y': 0}, 
{'x': 1233360000, 'y': 0}]
```

Where `'x'` is the unix timestamp and `'y'` is the value for that time. 
How can I extract the values from the `'value'` dictionary and restructure them so that `'x'` is labelled `'date'` and structured in this format: `2011-09-13`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you assign what is kept in `'values'` to a variable called `lst` (e.g. `lst = data['value']`) you can use this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': np.array([subdct['x'] for subdct in lst], dtype='datetime64[s]'),
                   'y': [subdct['y'] for subdct in lst]})
```

With:

```
lst = [{'x': 1230940800, 'y': 0}, 
       {'x': 1231113600, 'y': 0}, 
       {'x': 1231286400, 'y': 0}, 
       {'x': 1231459200, 'y': 0}, 
       {'x': 1231632000, 'y': 0}, 
       {'x': 1231804800, 'y': 0}, 
       {'x': 1231977600, 'y': 0}, 
       {'x': 1232150400, 'y': 0}, 
       {'x': 1232323200, 'y': 0}, 
       {'x': 1232496000, 'y': 0}, 
       {'x': 1232668800, 'y': 0}, 
       {'x': 1232841600, 'y': 0}, 
       {'x': 1233014400, 'y': 0}, 
       {'x': 1233187200, 'y': 0}, 
       {'x': 1233360000, 'y': 0}]
```

This gives me this `df`:

```
         Date  y
0  2009-01-03  0
1  2009-01-05  0
2  2009-01-07  0
3  2009-01-09  0
4  2009-01-11  0
5  2009-01-13  0
6  2009-01-15  0
7  2009-01-17  0
8  2009-01-19  0
9  2009-01-21  0
10 2009-01-23  0
11 2009-01-25  0
12 2009-01-27  0
13 2009-01-29  0
14 2009-01-31  0
```

Comment: `btc_usd2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': np.array([subdct['x'] for subdct in btc_usd1], dtype='datetime64[s]'),
                   'y': [subdct['y'] for subdct in btc_usd1]})` TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: `btc_usd = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    btc_usd1 = pd.DataFrame(btc_usd)` comes before the code i just copied

Comment: I didn't mean you should use a `DataFrame` as the `lst` variable. What happens if you use `lst = btc_usd['values']` (from `btc_usd` - not the `btc_usd1`!) and then run my code?

Comment: That works, so instead of the original btc1, it becomes `btc_usd1=btc_usd['values']` and then run the method to convert to an array and fix the unix timestamp

Comment: How can I set the `date` column as the index?

Comment: @zsad512 You could use a `df = df.set_index('Date')` **afterwards**, where `df` has to be replaced by the variable name for your `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 2):

if i understood you correctly, pandas should be able to convert it to a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(values_dictionary).rename(columns={'x':'Date'})
```

then you can use the to_datetime to convert it to yyyy/mm/dd format:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str), unit='s')
```

output:

```
    Date        y
0   2009-01-03  0
1   2009-01-05  0
2   2009-01-07  0
3   2009-01-09  0
4   2009-01-11  0
5   2009-01-13  0
6   2009-01-15  0
7   2009-01-17  0
8   2009-01-19  0
9   2009-01-21  0
10  2009-01-23  0
11  2009-01-25  0
12  2009-01-27  0
13  2009-01-29  0
14  2009-01-31  0
```

Comment: This is close but does not work. I was able to extract the 'values' dictionary into a dataframe, but I need 'x' and 'y' to be separate columns.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding quite well what you mean. The dataframe df created has two columns: date and y. Date is x, but I renamed it as per your instructions.

Comment: This is a good answer.  One line if that means anything `pd.DataFrame(lst).rename(columns=dict(x='Date')).assign(Date=lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d.Date, unit='s'))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want a dictionary if all you want is the dates. You can do this and just get a list of the dates.

```
import datetime
dates = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(xydict['x']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for xydict in values]
```

EDIT: if you want this in a similar dictionary format:

```
import datetime 
dates = [{'date' : datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(xydict['x']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")} for xydict in values]
```

Comment: I want the keys (which are the dates) AND the corresponding values.

Comment: Can you provide the sample output that you are trying to get?